# Mysql cannot create foreign key error 121 but doesn't exists

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I have a strange problem, I'm trying to create a foreign key with a specific name but mysql says: "`Can't create table #sql-85f_169' (errno: 121)`" so I understand the name must be unique and it is, because there is no one with that name.

Complete story: We have 16 databases in one server (ubuntu server14) for multiple web pages with the same structure, same tables, same everything but different database name. 
Recently we add a new database for a new client, so we make a copy of another of the 16, we usually download one and replace the name of database and keep same structure. 
I need to add a new foreign key to a table "orders", so I deleted the 2 previous foreign keys, name were "order_ibfk_1" and "order_ibfk_2" and added 3 more:

```
ALTER TABLE `orders`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `order_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_reception`) REFERENCES `recepction` (`id_recepction`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `order_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_type_order`) REFERENCES `type_order` (`id_type_order`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `order_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_company`) REFERENCES `company` (`id_company`);
```

I did this on every of the 16 databases and worked fine, but not in the new one, the new database 17 show `(errno: 121)` but I already deleted all foreigns keys, the table is empty, I even deleted the entire table and make a new one and keep saying the same error. I checked the `information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` and the `KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` does not exist the name "order_ibfk_1" in this database. In `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G` section `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR` says duplicated name.

¿Maybe is in cache or something?, we already restarted the service and the server, this only happened on the production server, on local worked fine. This database and the others 16 are operational and working 24h so we cannot interrupt their work every time.

I'm thinking in deleting the database number 17 in the first chance, to later restore it. Also sometimes i get this error `#2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query` when I try to run the foreign key query, but only say that when working with phpmyadmin or ssh on that database 17, the same query on the others 16 does not make any error, I use `SET @@global.max_allowed_packet = 1048576*10;` to execute the query but same error 121. 
¿Any idea? ¿mysql is haunted?

Comment: just to be clear? you restarted the service and the server locally and on production or just locally?

Comment: As for the lost connection...I would check `dmesg` or your mysql error log. probably, mysql is crashing during the execution of the query as a result of not enough memory to alter the table...

Comment: @BK435 Production, next maintenance will be next week.

Comment: @BK435 with dmseg: 
`[31043.133026] init: mysql main process (3021) terminated with status 1`
`[31043.133042] init: mysql main process ended, respawning`

Mysql Log: 
`11:55:54 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ; key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=2
max_threads=151
thread_count=2
connection_count=2 `

and in the end: 
`151010  7:26:37 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './phpmyadmin/pma_recent' is marked as crashed and should be repaired`
`151010  7:26:37 [Warning] Checking table:   './phpmyadmin/pma_recent'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did:

I downloaded the database to use it in local, I try to run the sql and everything goes fine.

So I just downloaded the database, deleted it on the server, re-upload it and run the sql in the server and sudenly works perfectly. I guess was something in cache or memory.